# Compilation error in if-condition

Tags: java, compiler-errors, conditional-statements

At the very last condition, I was expecting to get the condition evaluated starting from the expression on the left of operator "&&" which becomes true and then the statement on the right
. However, I am getting compilation error here saying "syntax error on token "=", != expected".
Any explanation on this problem would be of great help.

```
boolean boolTrue=Boolean.TRUE;
    boolean assignBool=Boolean.FALSE;
    int ten=10;

    //eventually evaluates to true , runs okay
    if(assignBool=boolTrue){
        System.out.println("Executed");
    }
    //evaluates to true && true: runs correctly
    if( assignBool=boolTrue && ten==10 )
        System.out.println("Executed");

    //evaluates to true && true : runs correctly
    if( ten==10 && (assignBool=boolTrue)  )
        System.out.println("Executed");

    /*was supposed to evaluate to true && true : but gives compile error
    compiler expects me to use '!=' or '==' operator though the second statement ultimately evaluates to true 
    as in above case*/
    if( ten==10 && assignBool=boolTrue  )//Compile error
        System.out.println("Executed");
```

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answer. To check if it was operatar precedence issue, I ran same case in for loop and YES, that was it .

```
    boolean boolTrue=Boolean.TRUE;
    boolean assignBool=Boolean.TRUE;
    int ten=10;

    singleloop:
    for(int i=0;((ten==10 && assignBool)==boolTrue);System.out.println("Executed")){
        i++;
        if(i>10)
            break singleloop;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this a precedence issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is trying to evaluate the last `if` as if it were written

```
if( (ten==10 && assignBool)=boolTrue  )
```

which makes no sense because the left side is not an lvalue (to borrow some vocabulary from C). This is because `&&` has higher precedence than `=` in Java.

Comment: I am aware of that, but please look at the above scenario. In condition, if it evaluates to "true" or "false" , it has to be executed successfully. Which means, assignments evaluates ONLY for boolean.

Comment: @vandey - I elaborated my answer a bit.

Comment: thats what I felt like, but since I am using short circuit operator && , was not the compiler suppose to evaluate the right hand and left hand expression separately?

Comment: @vandey But it has to know which is "left" and "right", and it uses precedence to determine that. That aside, the *compilation* process happens long before *evaluation*, and you have a syntax error *because* of the precedence rules, which affect parsing.

Comment: @vandey - Operator precedence makes the right-hand expression `assignBool`, not `assignBool=boolTrue`.

Comment: @vandey - Note that your second case is not doing what you think. It is assigning to `assignBool` the result of evaluating `boolTrue && ten==10`, not the value of `boolTrue`.

Comment: @CrazyCasta - OP wants to understand why there's a syntax error in the last case. I was explaining that. I eliminated the first part of my answer, which was irrelevant (and, I admit, probably not what OP wants).

Answer (score 3):

I assume from your code that you are trying to play around and actually want to assign boolTrue to assignBool.

The problem is the order of operators. The && has higher precedence than = ([source](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php)). It is creating a bool by anding with the ten==10 expression. The result is a non-lvalue (an expression that cannot be written to). Your expression is equivalent to the fully parenthesized:

```
((ten == 10) && assignBool) = boolTrue
```

As you've already found out, the following is the way to do it:

```
ten==10 && (assignBool=boolTrue)
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the [nice table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) in the Java Tutorial, the assignment operator has the lowest precedence among all operators. That is, the expression

```
ten==10 && assignBool=boolTrue
```

is evaluated as

```
(ten==10 && assignBool) = boolTrue
```

but the left hand expression is not assignable.

If you want different precedence, you must use brackets, i.e.

```
ten==10 && (assignBool = boolTrue)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know java but it's probably binding && more strongly than your other operators.

Answer (score 1):

it's being evaluated as `if((ten==10 && assignBool)=boolTrue  )` which means you are trying to assign to a constant.